# Characters with apostrophe names

Tags: characters, naming, grammar

I have created a world, and one of the cultures has mainly apostrophe names - Vax'Ildan, Vex'Ahlia, Soih'Ym...

How would this work grammatically - possessive and nicknames, in writing?

(To forestall any comments or answers, no I cannot change their culture, or names - for argument's sake, say I'm writing fanfiction with these names already existing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as possessives, nothing should change provided the apostrophe that is part of the name does not appear as the final character in the name:

> Vex'Ahlia's coat would be fine, but
>
> A name like Sov'Yk' (not one of your examples, but just for argument's sake) would present its own problems.

(I would prefer to see Sov'Yk's shirt over Sov'Yk''s shirt, for example.)

As far as nicknames, you should be free to create variations on the character's name that sound natural.

Answer (score 1):

They all sound pretty good. As long as you keep the names in that direction (i.e. don't name one Fred out of nowhere), it should be completely fine. And like @RobJarvis said, make sure you keep the possessive of names like "Sov'Yk's", not "Sov'Yk"s".

Comment: @DM_with_secrets Oof yeah. Thanks